# Partial View não carrega Javascript - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partialview

Estou passando para uma Partial View através de um controller dois parâmetros, 
musica e artista. Já na PV eu passo para a função fetchLetra() que se encontra no arquivo letraAPI.js esses parâmetros para o retorno da function, porém, isso não esta ocorrendo por que aparentemente a Partial não esta carregando nenhum script,ela esta desta forma

```
@model letra.Infra.Models.Letra



@{
    var artista = Model.Artista.ToString();
    var musica = Model.Musica.ToString();
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/letraAPI.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    fetchLetra(artista, musica);
    alert("OK");
</script>
```

Carregando a pagina o HTML fica assim

```
    <div id="letraAPI" class="panel-content">



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vagalumeAPI.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        fetchLetra(artista, musica);
        alert("OK");
    </script>
</div>
```

nada acontece, nem mesmo o alert é executado.

Comment: `fetchLetra` é o quê? Uma função no arquivo `letraAPI.js`?

Comment: Exatamente jbueno!

Comment: Isso é pra ser executado logo que a tela é carregada? Não faltou colocar isso dentro de **`$(document).ready(function () {  });`**?

Comment: Não, isso é executando após uma ação de clique, que chama o controller e o controller passa os parâmetros necessários para Partial

Comment: Perai, você colocou código JS dentro da partial?

Comment: As referências estão na Partial por que elas estão na main e mesmo assim não esta funcionando, então achei que tinha que colocar nos dois lugares.
Um detalhe é que colocando essa função direto na main referenciando o arquivo letraAPI.js, funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Entenda, uma View (seja ela Partial ou não) serve para montar uma pagina HTML de forma dinâmica no lado do servidor,

então todo o codigo escrito dentro de `@{` e `}` é processado no lado do servidor (incluido `tags HTML`, estas também serão processadas pelo servidor) e não está disponível no lado do cliente. o que será enviado para o cliente é o resultado deste processamento, ou seja um `HTML`, `JavaScript` ou `CSS` validos.

```
@model letra.Infra.Models.Letra
@{
    var artista = Model.Artista.ToString();
    var musica = Model.Musica.ToString();
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/letraAPI.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var artista = @artista;
    var musica = @musica;
    fetchLetra(artista, musica);
    alert("OK");
</script>
```

no exemplo acima, a `View` irá montar um `script` de forma dinamica utilizando os valores `artista` e `musica`, mas lembre-se, que este `script` será executado apenas no `cliente` (que provavelmente é um `Browser`).

Answer (score 0):

Se vc fizer da forma abaixo, funciona, mas não precisa colocar o script na partial, se vc estiver chamando a mesma por ajax, daí dá pra chamar os métodos pelo callback "complete:".

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        fetchLetra(artista, musica);
        alert("OK");
    });
</script>
```